# Frailty Models for Death Rate

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I need to create a frailty-model (gompertz-gamma) for deathratesdue heterogeneity, having a dataset of people grouped by age and year of calendary with the following variables:

year, age , deaths, exposure

I have seen the R-Package "Parfm" , but the model requires a dependant variable:
Surv(time,event)

In the best scenario, is there a way to create this kind of model using GLM?

Is it possible to use the parfm model for deathrates? If possible, how can I re-write my dataset to make it ready for "Parfm" model?

If not possible, considering my low competences in R, is there another way to procede?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this was migrated from SO, but here goes:

`Surv(time, event)` is used just as written, only `time` should be the name of the column in your dataset that stores survival times, and `event` should be an indicator column telling whether the individual died at that time, or was censored. See `?Surv` for more details.
Also, I am not sure if your dataset is in long format now, i.e. one row per individual? You can use the example dataset `veteran` in R to see how it should look, and to try calling survival tests:

```
> head(veteran)
  trt celltype time status karno diagtime age prior
1   1 squamous   72      1    60        7  69     0
2   1 squamous  411      1    70        5  64    10
3   1 squamous  228      1    60        3  38     0
4   1 squamous  126      1    60        9  63    10
5   1 squamous  118      1    70       11  65    10
6   1 squamous   10      1    20        5  49     0
```

The formula for a survival model on this dataset could be something like `Surv(time, status) ~ celltype + trt`.